# Is it possible to pass $scope.value inside json object in Angularjs controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, api

I have a var data with json object defined. I want to dynamically change json fields from html and call slightly different POST APIs.
e.g:

```
var data={
    $scope.value:'25',
    'speciality':$scope.speciality,
    'field2':'something',
    'field3':'something else'
}
```

How can I change $scope.value can have 10 to 15 different values.
I tried doing,

```
var example=$scope.value;
var data={
  example:'25',
  'speciality':$scope.speciality,
  'field2':'something',
  'field3':'something else'
}
But this too doesn't work and sends example as json field.
```

Any help is apprciated.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is `$scope.value`? An array of strings? Do you always set the key to '25'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a variable as a property name, then you must create an object first, then assign the data using square bracket notation.

```
var data = {   
        'speciality':$scope.speciality,
        'field2':'something',
        'field3':'something else'
    }

data[$scope.value] ='25';
```

Comment: Thanks , this is what wanted.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have a key that dynamically changes. Your best bet is to build the object at the time you need it:

```
var obj = {};
obj[$scope.value] = 25;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    'field2':'something',
    'field3':'something else'
};
$scope.value.forEach(function(value) {
    data[value] = '25';
});
```